# Can't execute a string as a shell command in elisp

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp

```
(shell-command "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\stuff\\ctags58\\ctags.exe\" -eR -f \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\\TAGS\" \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\"")

(message "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\stuff\\ctags58\\ctags.exe\" -eR -f \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\\TAGS\" \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\"")
```

Executing the top form gives me the error `'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.  Executing the output the second form puts into the `*Messages*` buffer works as intended (creates a tags file).

Why am I not getting the same results with both techniques? Does `shell-command` do something that changes the string before sending it to the shell? How can I use elisp to execute a string exactly as if I had pasted it into a command prompt?

`shell-quote-argument` does not work either as it produces a string that cannot be executed with either method:

```
(message (shell-quote-argument "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\stuff\\ctags58\\ctags.exe\" -eR -f \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\\TAGS\" \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\""))
"^\"\\^\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\stuff\\ctags58\\ctags.exe\\^\" -eR -f \\^\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\\TAGS\\^\" \\^\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\ggustafson\\Desktop\\BlueTooth_7020\\^\"^\""
```

Comment: It is possible that you use different versions of `ctags.exe`. Can you try with a full path.

Comment: Look up `C-h f shell-quote-argument`

Comment: @slitvinov I was using full paths the entire time, so AFAIK this is a problem with emacs and not ctags. Edited question to clarify that.

Comment: @phils I have, see the question, but I do not see how it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shell-quote-argument` is for quoting a single *argument* to a shell command (hence the name), not a shell command in its entirety.

Given that the error you were seeing suggested a lack of quoting somewhere, it seemed like a good idea to use the built-in command to deal with quoting rather than writing it manually and assuming you had the correct syntax.

Another alternative is using <kbd>M-!</kbd> to execute the command (or a similar one) interactively, figure out what gets accepted, and then afterwards use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd> to obtain the elisp form.

Comment: +1 For using `C-x M-:` to obtain the elisp form of the last command. For some reason I needed to [put the quotes around only the directory with a space in it](http://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks) and not the whole path. This is what worked on a different machine: `(message "c:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\\"ctags 58\"\\ctags.exe -f \"c:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\TAGS\" \"c:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\ctags 58\\\"")`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to doublecheck both if executions are using same path, and therefore same `ctags.exe`.  I think that might be the problem.  You may want to use the full path to `ctags.exe` to make sure of that.

My ctags (Linux) gives me the same error if I use the `-Re` option on a normal shell; that is what makes me think that way.

Comment: I was in the same directory as `ctags.exe` during both tests. Edited the question to better clarify where the issue is coming from. :)

Comment: Answer addressed the original problem you stated (before you edited the question).  And I think the issue you are having might be even related... Are the shell that shell-command uses and the shell you are manually pasting the command the same shell?  I am not sure if in Windows you can do a `(shell-command "echo $0")` to verify.

Comment: I have been executing the commands from within emacs with the buffer produced by the `shell` command. I believe both that and `shell-command` are using emac's cmdproxy.exe, but I'm looking for a way to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you use `call-program` instead of `shell-command` here, since you don't use any of the features of the shell, and it just gets in the way, forcing you to do quoting gymnastics to explain to the shell what you mean.